# nhibernate.linq simple (read dumb) question

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I'm trying to wrap my head around linq -> nhib

I have a simple bit of sql that i'm trying to get working in nhibernate.linq

```
 select * from 
 ColModel where ColModel.DataIndex 
 not in ('CostElement1', 'CostElement2', 'CostElement3')
 and ColModel.ReportId = 1
```

The list of excluded `DataIndex` values comes in in the form of a `List<string>` called `excludeNames`

Here is what I have tried but it seems that it's not really feeling the love:

```
var s = base._sessionManager.OpenSession();

var query = from col in s.Linq<ColModel>()
            where col.Report.Id == reportid &&
            !(from c in s.Linq<ColModel>() select c.DataIndex).Contains(excludeNames)
            select col;

return query.ToList();
```

the error:

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

I'm pretty sure I'm borfing this from the offset so any pointers would be well appreciated :)

w://

Comment: I'm not familiar with linq with nhibernate, but should the Contains statement not be the other way round? Otherwise, aren't you checking that a single dataIndex contains a list of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contains doesn't accept a list.

There are ways to work around this in LINQ, but I'm not sure which, if any, of those will work in NH Linq

Answer (score 0):

I think you have your exclusion backwards.

```
s = base._sessionManager.OpenSession();

var query = from col in s.Linq<ColModel>()
            where col.Report.Id == reportid &&
                  !excludeNames.Contains(col.DataIndex)
            select col;

return query.ToList();
```

Collection.Contains(item) will produce the SQL `item in (...collection...)`, adding the negation will get you what you want.